# is there any way to find XPATH?

Tags: python, selenium, facebook, xpath

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import re
loc = "chromedriver.exe"
chrome_profile_loc = "C:\\Users\\hello\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data"

WORD = "tattoo"
Location = 'Lund, Sweden'

emails = []

def check(email):
    """
    Function to check if an email is valid
    """
    if re.match(r'^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$', email):
        return True
    else:
        return False

def search_data():
    """
    Function to search for the specified word and location on Facebook
    """
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument("user-data-dir="+chrome_profile_loc)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=loc,options=chrome_options)
    driver.get("https://www.facebook.com")
    search_bar = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//input[@type="search"]')
    search_bar.send_keys(WORD)
    search_bar.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='_586i']").click()
    location_input = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@placeholder='Search by city, country, or address']")
    location_input.send_keys(Location)
    location_input.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    time.sleep(5)
    # Scroll down to load more search results
    actions = ActionChains(driver)
    while True:
        actions.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN).perform()
        time.sleep(2)
        if 'No more posts to show' in driver.page_source:
            break
        return driver.page_source


def SaveLinks(page_source):
    """ Function to extract and filter links from search results """
    links = re.findall(r'(https?://www.facebook.com/[a-zA-Z0-9.]+)', page_source)
    for link in links:
        if '/profile.php?id=' in link:
            emails.append(link)

def main():
    """ Main function to call all other functions """
    page_source = search_data()
    SaveLinks(page_source)
    for email in emails:
        if check(email):
            print(email)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

i can't find XPATH, on facebook please help

I downloaded XPATH finder but on facebook it doesn't work

Comment: here is the whole code those who want to help me  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_pvCw2jehTi_QOQtD2JJIS_SFr-3jcDt/view?usp=share_link

Comment: What element XPath are you trying to find? Waht search bar can be before logging into the facebook?

Comment: Which of the 3 `driver.find_element` give you error? And what element of the page are you trying to target with the xpath?

Comment: it's a bot that collects emails from companies so it should search for txe tattoos and then go into places and then collect emails

Comment: all 3 become eror it doesn't work it doesn't find the way/XPath

Comment: Replace the line `search_bar = driver...` with `search_bar = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//input[@type="search"]')`. Try and let me know if it works

Comment: @soundwave look bro https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pDDtClShtvRUOP8sDPowF4KP_hRw6u8N/view?usp=share_link

Comment: is not working pls help my friends

Comment: That error `ElementNotInteractableException` could mean that the search bar is not visible in the browser. Is it visible or not when the code is executed? Look here works fine to me https://i.imgur.com/Djf6q4p.png

Comment: can you check my code if it is ok https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_pvCw2jehTi_QOQtD2JJIS_SFr-3jcDt/view

Comment: As I told you before, you have to replace `search_bar = driver.find_element("By.XPATH, /html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/label/input']")` with the followin `search_bar = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//input[@type="search"]')`

Comment: look now bro on this link https://drive.google.com/file/d/1N_UOfdLWk8w1sGqfuy-aJXZ2FsjREXGC/view?usp=share_link

Comment: put all the code in the question instead of google drive

Comment: Is the search bar visible in the browser when the code is executed?

Comment: new to this what do you mean

Comment: I don't know how to put it in the question

Comment: Look here https://i.imgur.com/t0mNisq.png click edit then put the full code

Comment: Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.   look bro it says so

Comment: Paste all the code in the editor, then select all the code with the mouse and then press CTRL+K. The code will be indented

Comment: check now is it good?

Comment: Ok good. With "Is the search bar visible in the browser when the code is executed?" I mean that the code works only if you can see the search bar in your browser, so if you don't see it you must scroll to the top of the browser so that you see the search on top left of the screen

Comment: what do you mean can you change my code bro

Comment: take a screenshot of what you see in the selenium browser, then send me a link of the screenshot

Comment: @soundwave how do you mene?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: what do you mean by selenium brower i use chromedriver

Comment: yes is the same, go to facebook home with chromedriver and send me a screenshot

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pDDtClShtvRUOP8sDPowF4KP_hRw6u8N/view?usp=share_link look bro

Comment: i didn't mean a screenshot of the code, just run the command `driver.get("https://www.facebook.com")` and take a screenshot of the browser, then send it here

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pDDtClShtvRUOP8sDPowF4KP_hRw6u8N/view?usp=share_link

Comment: I started my program but then it went into facebook then it shut down

Comment: run this code https://pastebin.com/z0zQMT8i

Comment: FYI. Facebook doesn't allow you to scrape them. So don't be surprised when you get banned.

Answer (score 0):

The XPATHs used in the code above may not work on Facebook anymore as the website's structure and layout can change over time. To find the current XPATHs for the elements you want to interact with on Facebook, you can use a tool like the Chrome DevTools. Open the website in Chrome, right-click on the element you want to find the XPATH for, and select "Inspect". The DevTools window will open, and the element will be highlighted in the HTML structure. Right-click on the highlighted element and select "Copy" > "Copy XPATH". This will give you the current XPATH for that element, which you can use in your code.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).